# Cooking Large Quantity of Chicken Legs

Tags: chicken, cooking-time, roasting

When I roast or bake chicken legs (about 10) I roast them for about 2 hours on 350 wet so they never dry out.   I am cooking today nearly 100 legs in 3 full size pans (32 legs each pan) for a buffet table.   How much longer will I need to roast them so the meat pulls back from the bone and they are tender.  I will still roast them "wet" and covered.   I also have access to commercial convection ovens.

Comment: Cooking meat wet is no guarantee that they'll be tender if cooked for too long.  Meat dries out due to the constriction of the muscle fibers which will occur even if they are completely submerged in water.  This process starts at a hair over 120F and higher temps accelerate this process.  As soon as the meat gets to this temperature and until it is below this temperature, moisture loss occurs.  The best method to prevent this is the confit method.

Answer (score 1):

Id suggest turning the heat down to 300 and giving them around 3 to 3 and half hours. Keeping it low means if the buffet is late which is often the case they won't dry out left in the oven.